# Spring Scheduling - Cron expression for everyday at midnight not working?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron, spring-data-rest

I am trying to schedule a task in Spring which is to be run everyday at midnight. I followed the [official guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) from Spring and made the scheduler class as below:

```
@Component
public class OverduePaymentScheduler {    
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *")
    public void trackOverduePayments() {
        System.out.println("Scheduled task running");
    }
}
```

However the task does not run when the clock hits 12am. I got the cron expression from the documentation for quartz scheduler at this [link](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger).

The scheduler is executed fine if I change the cron expression to "*/10 * * * * *" which runs every ten seconds.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you are on spring 5.3.3 or above, try @Scheduled(cron = "@midnight"). Cron expressions can be hard to read for a human eye.

ref: https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/10/new-in-spring-5-3-improved-cron-expressions

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I finally got it to work with this cron expression `0 0 0 * * *` but I had to set the time zone in the scheduler class like this.
`@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *",zone = "Indian/Maldives")`

Answer (score 124):

These are valid formats for cron expressions:

- `0 0 * * * *` = the top of every hour of every day.
- `*/10 * * * * *` = every ten seconds.
- `0 0 8-10 * * *` = 8, 9 and 10 o'clock of every day.
- `0 0 6,19 * * *` = 6:00 AM and 7:00 PM every day.
- `0 0/30 8-10 * * *` = 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, 10:00 and 10:30 every
  day.
- `0 0 9-17 * * MON-FRI` = on the hour nine-to-five weekdays
- `0 0 0 25 12 ?` = every Christmas Day at midnight

The pattern is:

```
second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday
```

So your answer is:

```
0 0 0 * * *
```

Comment: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'Cleanup': Range exceeds maximum (24): '24' in expression "0 0 24 * * . We cannot use 24

Comment: User 0 0 0 * * * to run every midnight

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

Answer (score 21):

Please use below cron pattern for 12:00 AM every day:

```
    // at 12:00 AM every day
    @Scheduled(cron="0 0 0 * * ?")
```

I have checked your cron pattern at this website:http://www.cronmaker.com/.

It says pattern `0 0 0 * * *` as invalid.

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: I have used this cron pattern in my project . it works well ... i have tested right now also by changing my system clock time to 11:59 PM and the scheduler is triggered automatically at 12:00 AM

Comment: cronmaker isn't compatible with Spring cron expressions, sadly.

Comment: this does not work for me spring boot version 2.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: @AshishUpadhyay what is the exception you are getting

Comment: no exception, just not running however 0 0 0 * * * is running perfectly fine without setting the zone

Answer (score 5):

For spring 5.3 or above users, we have a much simpler way to define crons

| Macro | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `@yearly (or @annually)` | once a year (0 0 0 1 1 *) |
| `@monthly` | once a month (0 0 0 1 * *) |
| `@weekly` | once a week (0 0 0 * * 0) |
| `@daily (or @midnight)` | once a day (0 0 0 * * *) |
| `@hourly` | once an hour, (0 0 * * * *) |

ref: https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/10/new-in-spring-5-3-improved-cron-expressions

Comment: `SpringVersion.getVersion()` to get current version of Spring.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below format to satisfy your requirement:

**0 0 23 * * ***

Since the hours starts from 0 to 23 for Quartz configuration.
You can refer this [link](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) for more information.