# Configure schedule in spring boot range hour

Tags: spring, schedule

Hello guys

I want to work my schedule at every minute between 8am - 10pm.
I tried that code.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 8-22 * * MON-FRI")
```

But it doesn't work! I am confused. Help me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[you can find out crontab information StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124756/spring-scheduling-cron-expression-for-everyday-at-midnight-not-working)

These are valid formats for cron expressions:

```
0 0 * * * * = the top of every hour of every day.
*/10 * * * * * = every ten seconds.
0 0 8-10 * * * = 8, 9 and 10 o'clock of every day.
0 0 6,19 * * * = 6:00 AM and 7:00 PM every day.
0 0/30 8-10 * * * = 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, 10:00 and 10:30 every day.
0 0 9-17 * * MON-FRI = on the hour nine-to-five weekdays
0 0 0 25 12 ? = every Christmas Day at midnight
```

The pattern is:

```
second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday
```

Comment: Thanks man!, it's working my case!