# Spring scheduler cron expression for everyday midnight

Tags: spring, spring-scheduled

I am trying to write one cron expression to run it in everyday in midnight (12:00 AM).

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * ?")
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestScheduler {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final TestService testService;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * ?")
    public void anonymizedApplicant() {
        testService.getUsers().forEach(user -> {
            userService.remove(user.getId());
        });
    }

}
```

is it correct expression if not, could someone help me to write this.

Comment: Did you try e.g. https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html?

Comment: I prepared this expression from there only, but after setting this value. Cron not waiting for 12.A.M and its keeping running.

Comment: What do you mean *"its keeping running"*? Please give a [mre] and explain the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: I updated the example with full code and observed behavior cron is running after each min.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Scheduling - Cron expression for everyday at midnight not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124756/spring-scheduling-cron-expression-for-everyday-at-midnight-not-working)

Comment: Its working fine, I had to restart the application.